# what to check syntax for twig file. (twig file syntax checker)

Tags: symfony, twig

I am using twig file in my application.

I have a newly coded file, and i am using that for sending emails i.e the email template is coded in that file.

It throws syntax error saying "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDIF in" .

Its getting difficult to debug a heavyly coded file.

Could anybody suggest help, how do i parse the file, for syntax checking.

Did a lot of google-ing.. Was not able to fine right syntax checker.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try [`twig:lint`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Command/LintCommand.php)?

Answer (score 1):

Use try catch for this:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

try {
    $content = $this->renderView(
        'AcmeHelloBundle:Hello:index.html.twig'
    );
} catch(\Exciption $e) {
    $message = $e->getMessage();
    var_dump($message); die; // do something with error
}

return new Response($content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the file into sections and view each section in the browser to try and determine where the problem lies. I always split code into several files rather than having thousands of lines of code in one file, although this isn't always possible.